# How to join mutilines in the Notepad++?

Tags: join, notepad++, lines

In the Notepad++, I have thousands lines of data need to modify, some of them in one appropriate line and end by "$", some data should have in one line but now arrange in several lines, so how to join them together and all end by "$"?
Here is the data sample:

```
1.we love it $      
2.its beautiful $
3.how

  can

  it? $
4. yes I love it $
5. sorry
   its
   ugly
   too $
```

for that sample, line 1,2,4 in the right line, but for line 3 and 5, it separates into multi-lines, so how to join them together?PS: except all the ends it has $, in other contents it has no one more "$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex replace:

```
find: (?<!\$)[\n\r]+(( ) *)?
replace: $2
```

The `$2` preserves one of the leading spaces (if any) from the joined line.

---

Given your input, the above produces:

```
1.we love it $
2.its beautiful $
3.how can it? $
4. yes I love it $
5. sorry its ugly too $
```

Note that your sample input is "corrupt" in that it has trailing spaces after `$` (eg the first line), so you'll have to clean that up first.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that about the first line too, and had to change it in my example. Nice pointing that out.

Comment: thank you, but why when use that, it only left(or form) one line? Also, I forget one situation, and edit the original post for data line 3.

Comment: @Andi See latest edit to my answer. Please also note that the first line of your sample input has trailing spaces in the first line, which must be removed (via `find: \$ +$` and `replace: $`) before this answer will work.

Comment: Also, I use "[^\$][\r\n]+" in replace, it works for data sample 5, but not work well in data sample 3, that's a little weird...

Comment: It works for me. Perhaps you have trailing *tabs*. Try: `find: \$\s+$` with `replace: $`

Comment: Thank you, it works well, thanks again for your precious help, also do you know why they give me a -1?

Comment: @Andi np. My guess as to the -1 is you didn't show any attempt at solving the problem yourself.